# Paypal android sdk, response Internal server error

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Im new to Paypal integration.

Im getting Internal server error when running SampleApp with Sandbox mode.  Yesterday Its worked fine.

> 08-29 19:22:49.141: E/paypal.sdk(1036): request failure with http
>   statusCode:500,exception:org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException:
>   Internal Server Error 08-29 19:22:49.146: E/paypal.sdk(1036): request
>   failed with server
>   response:{"name":"ACCOUNT_CANNOT_BE_FETCHED","message":"Account can
>   not be
>   fetched.","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#ACCOUNT_CANNOT_BE_FETCHED","debug_id":"c06d088d20e95"}

though Pay With Card, working fine. Not really sure what is the issue Pay With PayPal account.

Please let me know how to fix this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you try again?  I saw this error on sandbox earlier as well and when I tried again just now and it is working.  There may have been a temporary issue on sandbox that has been resolved.

Comment: Yes, I see its working fine today. and as you said i think its a temporary issue in sandbox. Thank you for reply...